# Real rooted univariate polynomial induced by a homogeneous polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $e\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose we have a homogeneous $h(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$  satisfying 
$$
h(e)\neq 0
$$
and 
$$
h(te-x)\in\mathbb{R}[t] \text{ is real rooted for all } x\in\mathbb{R}^n.
$$
We call the polynomial $h$ is **hyperbolic** with respect to $e\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

According to the notes I read, the hyperbolic polymonial $h(x)$ can be writed as

\begin{equation}\label{eq:qq}
h(te-x) = h(e)\prod_{j=1}^d(t-\lambda_j(x)).
\end{equation}

This is where I don't understand. And my question is how to get the  equation I mentioned above.

I know a property of  homogeneous polynomial is that 
$$h(tx)=t^dh(x)$$
where $t\in \mathbb{R}$  is the degree of  the homogeneous polynomial $h(x)$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, but I cannot deduce the  equation from that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By homogeneity, $h(x)$ is a sum of a bunch of monomials of same degree, say $d$; you can then write it as
\begin{equation}
h(x)=h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{I\subseteq [n]: \vert I\vert=d} c_I \prod_{i\in I} x_i, \quad c_I\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
Now, think of $x$ as fixed, and now think of $f(t):=h(te-x)=h(te_1-x_1,\ldots,te_n-x_n)$ as a polynomial in $t$. From the above, explicitly
\begin{equation}
f(t)=\sum_{I\subseteq [n]: \vert I\vert=d} c_I \prod_{i\in I} (te_i-x_i).
\end{equation}
The coefficient of $t^d$ in this comes from, when expanding the monomials, always picking the $te_i$. So the coefficient of $t^d$ is 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{I\subseteq [n]:\vert I\vert=d} c_I\prod_{i\in I} e_i=h(e)\neq 0,
\end{equation}
where the last part is by assumption. So now $f(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$ of degree $d$, and therefore has roots $\lambda_1(x),\ldots,\lambda_d(x)$. The only thing you need to get the factorization is the leading order coefficient, which is $h(e)$. This gives you the expression
\begin{equation}
f(t)=h(e)\prod_{i=1}^d (t-\lambda_i(x)).
\end{equation}